# Swift adaptive cell height in static tableview

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I am creating a static tableview to as my page will have a mixture of text and images in different rows.

Here is an example.  This was created in obj c webView, but i want to use Swift and be native, no webview

[image: dd]

Here is the code in my tableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class AdaptiveRowTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()


       self .tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      self .tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool ) {
       tableView.reloadData()
}

}
```

I have set the row height to 0.

I have tested with a label and an image.  The label works fine, but the image's row is not adjusting correctly.

Here is the result.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix the image row height?

Comment: I think you need to follow this tutorial [Dynamic Table View Cell Height](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I saw that site, but could not associate this with what i was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice [apple video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/) where you can find how to create adaptive cell height from minute 24.

You have to create constraints between the text and image and the cell and create relationships between them. Basically set a top and bottom constraint between text and cell and create a height relationship between text and image.

Comment: Thank you.  This video helped a lot.